# How to echo all video ids using php youtube data api php

Tags: php, youtube

Hello friends I want to echo ( print ) only YouTube video ids on screen using `php`.

here it is my code so  far. can  any one please tell me how to just show videos id nothing else thanks.

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?maxResults=5&part=snippet&key=API_KEY");
$array = json_decode ($data,true);
print_r ($array);
```

Comment: i have already posted the code man. array have all info like video title desc. etc. i just need video id

Comment: So you've basically tried nothing and not posted the data you have. Okay. You've also posted your API key which is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've adjusted the script for you so that it will retrieve the video id.

**Tested and working snippet**

```
 <?php
$apiKey = "enter-your-apikey-here";
$data = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?maxResults=5&part=snippet&key=".$apiKey);
$array = json_decode ($data,true);
foreach($array['items'] as $data) {
     var_dump($data['id']['videoId']); 
}
```